# Innerglow effect into css3

Tags: css, photoshop

I was wondering if I could reproduce an inner glow effect on a shape with css3.
Globally the setting of my effect is the following:

[image: Photoshop effect, consider only the inner glow]

I tried the following css code but it does not fit : is there something missing ?

```
background-color: #58585a;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 90px rgba(4,3,48, 0.30);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 90px rgba(4,3,48, 0.30); 
box-shadow: inset 0 0 90px rgba(4,3,48, 0.30);
```

The rgb color (4 3 48) is the one which is defined in the structure case.

Sorry I uploaded the two results so you can see the difference Here is the photoshop shape I would like to have (you can see that the inner shadow is less big than in the other one) http://www.anselme.info/img/photoshop-shape.png

Here is the web shape that I have using the css3 code mentioned above
http://www.anselme.info/img/webshape-with-css3.png

Comment: I got the same CSS code using your innerglow affect. What do you mean by telling *not fit*?

Comment: sorry, I uploaded the two renders and edited my post. Anyway thanks for   your time

Comment: Try the `spread parameter`. I don't know the exact number, but it's almost there. For example, `box-shadow: inset 0 0 90px 20px rgba(4,3,48,.3);` looks good. Here is the [preview](http://jsfiddle.net/Witcher42/2U5Pg/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 90px 0px rgba(3,3,46,0.9);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 90px 0px rgba(3,3,46,0.9);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 90px 0px rgba(3,3,46,0.9);
```